# Chaining jade renders, in node.js with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I would like to use Jade to render multiple parts,
and I need a little bit of script in 
between. I was trying something simple first:

```
// con is a mysql connection, res is a express render target
function main_page_jade(con, res)
{
    con.query('SELECT * FROM ' + 'pg_user' , function(err,rows,fields) {
        res.render( 'table.jade', {rows:rows, fields:fields, title:'DB User'} );
        con.query('SELECT * FROM ' + 'pg_comp' , function(err,rows,fields) {
            res.render( 'table.jade', {rows:rows, fields:fields, title:'DB Comp'} );
        });
    });
}
```

This does not work at all, so I googled around a bit, and the suggestions seemed
convoluted (Actually, spaghetti). I'm pretty new to node/js/jade (like 10 days new),
and probably a bit C++ biased (like 20yr biased), so my question is;
*How do I compose my project in a way that leads to good design, in node*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function main_page_jade(con, res) {
    var data = [];
    con.query('SELECT * FROM ' + 'pg_user' , function(err,rows,fields) {
        data.push({rows:rows, fields:fields, title:'DB User'});
        con.query('SELECT * FROM ' + 'pg_comp' , function(err,rows,fields) {
            data.push({rows:rows, fields:fields, title:'DB Comp'});
            res.render('index', {data: data});
        });
    });
}
```

And in your jade template:

```
each val in data
   //- Your current template
```

Answer (score 1):

@no_joke's answer is Perfect. To add a little explanation to that answer: You `render` **only once**. Compose all the data beforehand and then pass it to the template. For "spaghetti" code (which I think if what you're referring to is [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)), then promises or [ES7's async-await](http://www.sitepoint.com/simplifying-asynchronous-coding-es7-async-functions/) are your answer

Comment: that was an interesting link